# Navigation bar dropdowns not working on a wider screen

Tags: html, css, navigation

Currently I'm trying to replicate this navbar https://www.codingnepalweb.com/responsive-dropdown-menu-bar-html-css/ for my webpage. This navbar is set on a fixed position so whenever I scroll, it stays in the particular position. I didn't want this, so I changed it to relative position. But doing so made the dropdowns in the navbar unusable as whenever I try to access the options, the dropdown goes away. How do I make it so that the navbar is not fixed and the dropdowns are still accessible.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mopsa-71uzh?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-search"/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu"/>
      <label for="show-menu" class="menu-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <div class="content" style={{width:"100%"}}>
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Image</a></div>
        <ul class="links">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="desktop-link">Features</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-features"/>
            <label for="show-features">Features</label>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="desktop-link">Services</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-services"/>
            <label for="show-services">Services</label>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 3</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="desktop-link">More Items</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="show-items"/>
                <label for="show-items">More Items</label>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

.CSS

```
@media (max-width: 740px) {
  .topnav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 740px) {
  .logoImage {
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  background: #0e2043;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav .content .links {
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: flex;
}
.content .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
@media (max-width: 739px) {
  .logoImage {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
.content .links li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.content .links li a,
.content .links li label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 9px 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.content .links li label {
  display: none;
}
.content .links li a:hover,
.content .links li label:hover {
  background: #323c4e;
}
.wrapper .search-icon,
.wrapper .menu-icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper #show-search:checked ~ .search-icon i::before {
  content: "\f00d";
}
.wrapper .search-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper #show-search:checked ~ .search-box {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.search-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #171c24;
  padding: 0 100px 0 15px;
}
.search-box input::placeholder {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
.search-box .go-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  background: #171c24;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
/* Dropdown Menu code start */
.content .links ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #171c24;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content .links li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.content .links ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.content .links ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(-100% + 8px);
}
.content .links ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.content .links ul li:hover ul {
  top: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1251px) {
  nav .content .links {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
/* Responsive code start */
@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  .wrapper nav {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  nav .content .links {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .content .links li a {
    padding: 8px 13px;
  }
  .wrapper .search-box {
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .wrapper .search-box input {
    padding: 0 100px 0 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .wrapper .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper #show-menu:checked ~ .menu-icon i::before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav .content .links {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: #14181f;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  nav #show-menu:checked ~ .content .links {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .content .links li {
    margin: 15px 20px;
  }
  .content .links li a,
  .content .links li label {
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .content .links li a.desktop-link {
    display: none;
  }
  /* dropdown responsive code start */
  .content .links ul,
  .content .links ul ul {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    background: none;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .content .links #show-features:checked ~ ul,
  .content .links #show-services:checked ~ ul,
  .content .links #show-items:checked ~ ul {
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
  .content .links ul li {
    margin: 7px 20px;
  }
  .content .links ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper nav {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .content .logo a {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  .wrapper .search-box {
    max-width: calc(100% - 70px);
  }
  .wrapper .search-box .go-icon {
    width: 30px;
    right: 0;
  }
  .wrapper .search-box input {
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting unnecessaries properties for `.content .links ul`. You should do it this way: (I commented what you need to remove)

```
.content .links ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #171c24;
  // z-index: -1;
  // opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content .links li:hover > ul {
  // opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```